# void* function pointer array cast

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, function-pointers

I have an array which looks like this:

```
void* functions[]; // pointer to functions, each function returns an int and has int parameters A and B
```

I would like to cast this into the following:

```
int (*F)(int a, int b) = ((CAST HERE) functions)[0];
int result = F(a, b);
```

I have already tried "(int (*)(int, int))" as the cast but the compiler complained I am trying to use the function pointer as an array.

Comment: The compiler is right. Check your parentheses.

Comment: May try: `int (*F)(int, int) = (int (*)(int,int))functions[0];`

Comment: Use a typedef...

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot @M.M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`function` is an array of pointers to data of type `void`. You want to cast it to a pointer to pointers of type `int (*)(int, int)` which would be `int (**)(int, int)`, so the following works:

```
int (*F)(int, int) = ((int (**)(int, int)) functions)[0];
```

As pointed out by [@M.M](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46387557/4624294), the above will result in **undefined behaviour**. You might want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696918/c-cast-void-pointer-to-function-pointer) post and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3941867/4624294) for more on that.

---

Ideally, you would do something like this:

```
// Array of 2 pointers to functions that return int and takes 2 ints
int (*functions[2])(int, int) = {&foo, &bar};

// a pointer to function
int (*F)(int, int) = functions[0];
int r = F(3, 4);
```

Comment: This causes undefined behaviour

Comment: I tested this and it seemed to work for my application, thank you!

Comment: @Jas - Undefined behavior doesn't mean "not work". It may "seem to work" for a long time, until it breaks for no apparent reason upon moving to a new platform. By then you'd have forgotten this post and had to do overtime to figure out where you messed up.

Comment: Hmm I see, but isn't a typedef just an alias? Wouldn't the compiler treat both approaches in the same manner

Comment: @Jas - You don't have to use a typedef to follow M.M's approach. The key point is that the indexing must happen before the cast. `F = (int(*)(int, int))(functions[0]);`. But then again, an array of `void*` that holds function pointers is not something the C language standard supports.

Comment: @M.M thanks for pointing that out! Learnt something new today!. I had assumed that all pointers would be the same size.

Comment: @derFlower even if they are, the language standard doesn't allow aliasing them. You have to use an expression that performs a conversion, e.g. in StoryTeller's suggestion the value `functions[0]` is converted to function pointer.

Answer (score 4):

It will help to use a typedef for the function type:

```
typedef int F_type(int, int);
```

Then you can write:

```
F_type *F = (F_type *)(functions[0]);
```

It would be undefined behaviour (strict aliasing violation) to try and cast `functions` to something else before using the index operator.

Note that it is not supported by Standard C to convert `void *` to be function pointers. If possible, make the array be function pointers in the first place:

```
F_type *functions[] = { &func1, &func2 };
```

---

NB. Some people prefer using a typedef for the function pointer type, instead of the function type. I think it makes for more readable code to avoid pointer typedefs, but I mention this so you can make sense of other suggestions.

Comment: Good answer, but I am afraid OP doesn't want a `typedef`.

Comment: @gsamaras sure. I downvoted your answer as it will cause undefined behaviour .  Also what is your basis for claiming OP doesn't want a typedef?

Comment: Oh really? Hmm I am not sure why, could you please explain? Ah I might be wrong, since nm told OP about the typedef, then the OP answered I cannot do that, but he was answering to mm.. Sorry!

Comment: @gsamaras I mentioned in my answer... it aliases `void *` as a different type, which is a strict aliasing violation  (unrelated types can not be aliased in general)

Comment: I appreciate this safer approach @M.M, thank you very much for it, but the problem is that I was using a third party library for this and wanted to keep it simple. So yes I was avoiding typedefs.

Comment: This really ought to have been the accepted answer. Sometimes the only way to write reliable code is to not use the shortcuts in the other answers.

Comment: @M.M thanks, I updated my answer. How does it look like now? :D

Comment: @Jas I would say that using a typedef is simpler than not doing so

Answer (score 2):

Casting with `(int (**)(int, int))` might seem to do the trick now, but it invokes *Undefined Behavior*!

Converting `void*` to function pointer is not Standard C.

Note that aliasing `void*` to a different type; a strict aliasing violation. Read more in [What is the effect of casting a function pointer void?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305192/what-is-the-effect-of-casting-a-function-pointer-void)

Please consider using an array of function pointers from the start.

Comment: Aliasing and conversion are different things. Aliasing incompatible types violates the strict aliasing rule, it does not invoke a conversion. For a more stark example, compare `double d[2] = {5.0,6.0};  int x = d[0];` (conversion) versus `int y = ((int *)&d)[0];` (aliasing)